# The specified table does not exist on sql ce

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, windows-phone-7.1

I get an exception

```
The specified table does not exist [Limits]
```

while I'm trying saving new item

```
 (App.Current as App).context.Limits.InsertOnSubmit(new Limit() { Date = DateTime.Now, Value = inputLimit });//this works

 (App.Current as App).context.SubmitChanges();//here I get exception
```

Also I get an error on this line:

```
 var currentLimit = (App.Current as App).context.Limits.Where(l => l.Date.Date == DateTime.Now.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Here is a "model"

```
public class CalCounterContext:DataContext
{
    public CalCounterContext(string connstring):base(connstring)
    {
    }

    public Table<Limit> Limits;
    public Table<Meal> Meals;

}

[Table]
public class Limit
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes, doesn't. What could be a reson of my problem?

Comment: Could you provide a full exception message including the InnerException?

Comment: Are you checking when instantiating your datacontext if there is a database. Could you show the code where you are creating the database?

Comment: Sorry, for not answering you, but I couldn't reproduce this error. As soon I get it I answer you. Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 3):

This normally happens when you add a table in a later version of the database then what is being used.  When you create your database context, check to see if it is up to date, and if not, update the database using the DatabaseSchemaUpdater class as [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394022%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).  If it is just while you are creating the app, uninstall and re-install the app.

Also, I ran into a strange issue where intermittently I would get this error even once the app was in production without any reasoning.  Often is occured when I would launch the app and then hit the home or back button to end it quickly. I ended up re-implementing the GetTable<> function used to instantiate my ITable variable in a base database class so that it would do a hard check to see if the table actually existed:

```
public Table<TEntity> VerifyTable<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
    var table = GetTable<TEntity>();
    try
    {
        // can call any function against the table to verify it exists
        table.Any();
    }
    catch (DbException exception)
    {
        if (exception.Message.StartsWith("The specified table does not exist."))
        {
            var databaseSchemaUpdater = this.CreateDatabaseSchemaUpdater();
            databaseSchemaUpdater.AddTable<TEntity>();
            databaseSchemaUpdater.Execute();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```

Comment: thanks BK the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394022%28v=vs.92%29.aspx in your post really helped me lot.

Comment: Recently I have encounter this problem too, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same intermittent error you had. Try removing the database from the device and installing the app again. I found my issue was being caused because I was making changes to the model and when I re-ran the app, I would get this error.